# How to catch the Enter key received by Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, display

I got some code to receive characters from Bluetooth and code and print it back to the LCD display.

However, want to detect the *`Enter`* *character* to be the input signal, in other words, not to print nothing to the display until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

An strange character is shown at display for <kbd>Enter</kbd> but I can't *catch it*.

This is my code:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x20,16,2); 

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{

  while (Serial1.available())
  { 
    char dato= Serial1.read(); //Comprobamos el dato 

     lcd.print(dato);


    switch(dato) { 
    case '#':  
      Serial.println("GATO...");
    break;  
    case 'e':  digitalWrite(13,LOW); 

    Serial1.println("Led apagado");
    break;  
      case 'r':  
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH); delay(200); 
      digitalWrite(13,LOW); delay(200);

      Serial1.println("Led intermitente");
      break;
  } //fin switch

}//serial disponible


}//fin programa
```

Comment: How is this related to bluetooth?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what the enter key sends. It may be just CR (carriage return), LF (line feed), or both. You can check the [ASCII table](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/images/ASCII1.GIF) for the hex values for those characters.

LF is 0x0A and CR is 0x0D. Those are the characters you're looking for, you can add a `if` for these cases in order to guard the call to `lcd.print(dato)`:

```
char dato= Serial1.read(); //Comprobamos el dato 
if (dato != 0x0A && dato != 0x0F)
    lcd.print(dato);
```

Comment: I would use '\n' and '\r' instead of the ascii- if ( dato != '\n' && dato != '\r' ) ...

Comment: @imjosh yeah that's more readable.